# Cascade of state space models for linear systems

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have two linear control system that are represented by their state space models

$$\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
 A_1 & B_1 \\
\hline
 C_1 & D_1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c}
 A_2 & B_2 \\
\hline
 C_2 & D_2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

where $A_i$ is the state matrix, $B_i$ is the input matrix, $C_i$ is the output matrix and $D_i$ is the feedworward matrix.

The output of the first system is a vector signal of dimension $n$, which is the same dimension of the input signal of the second system. I want to put these two systems in cascade. How can I calculate the total space state model $(A_T, B_T, C_T, D_T)$?

Comment: A cascade is generally defined by a block diagram and not a state space realization. Without knowing how the systems are connected to each other its impossible to answer this.

Comment: I've a block with N inputs and T ouputs, and I've the second block with T inputs and P outputs. The output of the first block is used as input of second block. Since I can model a block with a transfer function, and it's possible to convert a transfer function to a state space model and vice-versa, there should be the possibility to calculate the state space model of the system obtained by connecting the output to the first block to the input of the second block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
(1) :\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{\dot x}_1=\boldsymbol{A}_1 \boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{B}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1 \\
\boldsymbol{y}_1=\boldsymbol{C}_1 \boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{D}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1
\end{cases}
$$

$$
(2): 
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{\dot x}_2=\boldsymbol{A}_2 \boldsymbol{x}_2+\boldsymbol{B}_2 \boldsymbol{u}_2 \\
\boldsymbol{y}_2=\boldsymbol{C}_2 \boldsymbol{x}_2+\boldsymbol{D}_2 \boldsymbol{u}_2
\end{cases}
$$

I assume you mean the output of the first system is the input of the second system which means

$$
\boldsymbol{u}_2=\boldsymbol{y}_1
$$

Then you can reform the second system as

$$
(2b)\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{\dot x}_2=\boldsymbol{A}_2 \boldsymbol{x}_2+\boldsymbol{B}_2 (\boldsymbol{C}_1 \boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{D}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1) \\
\boldsymbol{y}_2=\boldsymbol{C}_2 \boldsymbol{x}_2+\boldsymbol{D}_2 (\boldsymbol{C}_1 \boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{D}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1)
\end{cases}
$$

Combining (1) and (2b):

$$
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{\dot x}_1=\boldsymbol{A}_1 \boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{B}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1 \\
\boldsymbol{\dot x}_2=\boldsymbol{A}_2 \boldsymbol{x}_2+\boldsymbol{B}_2 \boldsymbol{C}_1\boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{B}_2 \boldsymbol{D}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1 \\
\boldsymbol{y}_2=\boldsymbol{C}_2 \boldsymbol{x}_2+\boldsymbol{D}_2 \boldsymbol{C}_1 \boldsymbol{x}_1+\boldsymbol{D}_2\boldsymbol{D}_1 \boldsymbol{u}_1
\end{cases}
$$

Let's make it neat:

$$\begin{cases}
&\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{\dot x}_1\\ \boldsymbol{\dot x}_2\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{A}_1 & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{C}_1 & \boldsymbol{A}_2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_1\\\boldsymbol{x}_2\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{B}_1\\
\boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{D}_1
\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{u}_1    \\
&\boldsymbol{y}_2&=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{D}_2\boldsymbol{C}_1&\boldsymbol{C}_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{x}_1\\\boldsymbol{x}_2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{D}_2\boldsymbol{D}_1\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{u}_1
\end{cases}
$$

Compacting as a new system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\boldsymbol{\dot x}=\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{B} \boldsymbol{u} \\
\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{C} \boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{u}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
& \boldsymbol{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{A}_1 & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{C}_1 & \boldsymbol{A}_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
& \boldsymbol{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{B}_1\\
\boldsymbol{B}_2\boldsymbol{D}_1
\end{bmatrix}\\
& \boldsymbol{C}=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{D}_2\boldsymbol{C}_1&\boldsymbol{C}_2\end{bmatrix} \\
& \boldsymbol{D}=\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{D}_2\boldsymbol{D}_1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have applied it as a [MATLAB function](https://gist.github.com/bencholmes/176adf5bbdb72c21da3f4b8c83c01880) for the purpose of cascading state space filters in case anyone who reads this is performing a similar task.

Comment: @loudnoises, good job. As a special case, if the system is SISO, you can alternatively multiply the transfer functions in one line.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand that, could you expand on what you mean by multiply the transfer functions in one line?

Comment: @loudnoises, I do not have matlab on my laptop to check it but I roughly mean  `sys_cascade=ss(tf(sys1)*tf(sys2));`

Comment: Oh right! Of course MATLAB will have in-built ways of doing these operations that will probably better than my method, I just like having code that isn't dependent on their system types. I use MATLAB Coder a lot and often their more advanced features won't compile so I need some homespun methods to get maximal performance.

Comment: @loudnoises, true and also I am not sure if it works for MIMO.